# Why are Menubutton not working in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, menu, ttk

Found a rather interesting way to create menus in the `Tkinter GUI` - `Menubutton`. But unfortunately this code does not work (or rather, when you click on `Menubutton` the bound Menu does not open):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

root.option_add("*Menu.borderWidth", "0")
root.option_add("*Menu.activeBorderWidth", "0")
root.option_add("*Menu.background", "black")


style = ttk.Style(root)


menu = tk.Menu(root)

btn_menu = ttk.Menubutton(root, text='fegvd')
btn_menu.pack()

file = tk.Menu(btn_menu, tearoff=0, foreground='white')
file.add_command(label='ГЫГ')

style.configure('TMenubutton', background='black', foreground='white', indicatoron=0, menu=file, direction='delow', state='active')

root.mainloop()
```

Although, if I use not `ttk.Menubutton`, but `tk.Menubutton`, then everything works:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

root.option_add("*Menu.borderWidth", "0")
root.option_add("*Menu.activeBorderWidth", "0")
root.option_add("*Menu.background", "black")


menu = tk.Menu(root)

btn_menu = tk.Menubutton(root, text='fegvd')
btn_menu.pack()


file = tk.Menu(btn_menu, tearoff=0, foreground='white')
file.add_command(label='ГЫГ')

btn_menu.configure(background='black', foreground='white', indicator=0, menu=file, state='active')

root.mainloop()
```

Why? Tell me, please, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the style to associate the menu with the menubutton. You need to do it exactly like you do with the `tk` menu:

```
btn_menu.configure(menu=file)
```

Comment: Tell me more, please, why the indicator in `ttk.Menubutton` is not removed?  I already tried all the settings, not one removes it :(

Comment: @DGDays: that's completely unrelated to this question and answer.